# Save extracted content from word document as CSV file

Tags: powershell, ms-word, export-to-csv

Successfully extract contents from Word document, but how can we save this as CSV file - where all data extracted goes in one row in CSV.

```
Clear-Host
function ExtractSectionsFromWordDoc{
    Param(
        [string]$SourceFile,
        [string]$SearchKeyword1,
        [string]$SearchKeyword2
    )
    $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $word.Visible = $false
    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($SourceFile, $false, $true)
    $sel = $word.Selection 
    $paras = $doc.Paragraphs 
    foreach ($para in $paras) { 
        if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword1) {
            $startPosition = $para.Range.Start
        }
        if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword2) {
            $endPosition = $para.Range.Start
            break
        }
    } 
    $doc.Range($startPosition, $endPosition).Copy() 
    $newdoc = $word.Documents.Add()
    $newdoc.Content.Paste()
    $newdoc.SaveAs("D:\testing\Search1.doc")
    $newdoc.Close()

    # cleanup com objects
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```

Document content is like this, which we want to save as one row in sql server
Description about the document :

```
SQL Server Versions:    
(a) SQL Server 2016 to be used for all upcoming projects;
(b) SQL Server 2016 Enterprise edition will be used on all servers
(c) Assumptions:
    (i) SQL Server will be installed on VM instances
```

Code I'm trying:

```
clear-host
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$Document=$Word.documents.open("D:\testing\Search1.doc", $false, $true)
$range = $Document.content
[array]$content = $range.Text 

$Output = $content | Out-String
$Output | Out-File d:\Testing\temptxt.txt
Import-CSV d:\Testing\temptxt.txt -Delimiter “|”| Export-CSV "D:\testing\temp.csv" -NoTypeInformation

#Get-Content $content | Export-Csv -Path "D:\Testing\Excelfile.csv" 
# cleanup com objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Document) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Try sending that data to `Export-CSV` cmdlet. That will give you all data in a single column. If you want it in a row, like one after the other, best way would be to convert that to a PSCustomObject [https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/] and then export it to csv.

Comment: Export-CSV gives me these rows not content from document
PSPath PSParentPath PSChildName PSDrive PSProvider ReadCount Length

Comment: You were doing `Get-ChildItem | Export-Csv` which won't do what you want. You need to build custom objects that have a property containing the text you want exported, then pass those objects to `Export-Csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom objects with a property that holds your text, then export those objects to a CSV:

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'foo' = $document.Content.Range.Text | Out-String
} | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: with this we get all the data in CSV file but we loose all formatting (like numbering part which was there in word doc), can that be resolved... or we will loose all formatting

Comment: CSV is a plaintext format. It will not retain any (Word) formatting.